# Problems with ItemListener in Java

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox, itemlistener

I am creating a simple Bold And Italic checkbox which will change the font style written in the text field t1. I did this but it dint help.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class S4 extends JFrame implements ItemListener{
    public S4(){
        setSize(300,150);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JCheckBox c1,c2;
        JTextField t1;
        Panel p1 = new Panel();
        c1 = new JCheckBox("Bold",false);
        c2 = new JCheckBox("Italic",false);
        t1 = new JTextField(40);
        p1.add(t1);
        p1.add(c1);
        p1.add(c2);        
        c1.addItemListener(this);
        c1.addItemListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(p1);
    }
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
        Font f;        
        if(c1.isSelected() && c2.isSelected()){
            f = new Font("Aerial",Font.BOLD+Font.ITALIC,13);
        }
        else if (c1.isSelected()){
            f = new Font("Aerial",Font.BOLD,13);
        }
        else if (c2.isSelected()){
            f = new Font("Aerial",Font.ITALIC,13);
       }
       else {
            f = new Font("Aerial",Font.PLAIN,13);
        }
        t1.setFont(f);
    }    
    public static void main(String [] args){
        new S4();
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't post a question. What is it that you're trying to do? What's not working?

Comment: Why did you add the itemlistener to c1 twice? I think you meant c1.addItemListener(this); c2.addItemListener(this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all you can't declare variables inside one method and then use them in another. You need to declare your `JCheckBox c1, c2;` and your `JTextField t1;` in the class itself.

Also take a look at where you add the listeners, you add the listener two times to `c1`. Where you want to add it once to `c1` and once to `c2`.

Here is your source code but with the small changes so it works!

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class S4 extends JFrame implements ItemListener {

    JCheckBox c1, c2;
    JTextField t1;

    public S4() {
         setSize(300,150);
         setVisible(true);
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         Panel p1 = new Panel();
         c1 = new JCheckBox("Bold",false);
         c2 = new JCheckBox("Italic",false);
         t1 = new JTextField(40);
         p1.add(t1);
         p1.add(c1);
         p1.add(c2);        
         c1.addItemListener(this);
         c1.addItemListener(this);
         getContentPane().add(p1);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
         Font f;        
         if(c1.isSelected() && c2.isSelected()){
             f = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD+Font.ITALIC,13);
         }
         else if (c1.isSelected()){
             f = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,13);
         }
         else if (c2.isSelected()){
             f = new Font("Arial",Font.ITALIC,13);
         }
         else {
             f = new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,13);
         }

         t1.setFont(f);
    } 

    public static void main(String [] args){
         new S4();
    }
}
```

Also the font you are using are spelled work, the font is spelled "Arial" unless, you are using a custom installed font. Like this once. http://www.dafont.com/aerial.font

Answer (score 0):

The font you are after is called "Arial"